# Windows 10 Search does not retrieve items from 2nd hard drive at all?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, search, updates, search-indexing

I have disabled Cortana after the Anniversary update, which was difficult. I cannot use the 'Search Windows' that has replaced Cortana to grab files from the computer (especially ones on the 2nd and 3rd Hard Drives)

I can search within 'Apps' (not really though) and 'Documents' by clicking their respective icons directly above the start menu **during** the search, and can sometimes get the file I am looking for by clicking '**more**' to the right of that, but it always says NO RESULTS FOUND for basic commonly used files from the 3rd drive.

Is there a way to fix this? I completely reinstalled W10 Pro and it's exactly the same. All drives are indexed, and in the index. Search just does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to a free program [UltraSearch](https://www.jam-software.com/ultrasearch). It performs faster than native utility.